# Issue with multiple instances of same UIView object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

I've got a problem at programming for iOS. Already looked for some similar problems but haven't found anything yet.

I'm creating at least 8 custom UIViews. As you can see in the appended code i'm running through a loop creating one instance per round. The reference of every object is on a different space in the memory but when i change a value in one object it only affects the object that has been created in the last loop-round (last created instance).
Any Ideas?

PadView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PadView : UIView {

}

- (void)setText:(NSString*)text;

@end
```

PadView.m:

```
#import "PadView.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h";

@implementation PadView

AVAudioPlayer *player;
UILabel *label;

- (void)setText:(NSString*)text {

    label.text = text;
}

- (void)initialize {

    label = [[ UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 93.0, 107.0, 13.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = @"Empty";
    [self addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder]) {

        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect]) {

        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Create the Objects:

```
NSMutableArray *pads = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    PadView *pad = [[PadView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, i*150, 107.0, 107.0)];
    [padsView addSubview:pad];
    [pads addObject:pad];
}
```

Call setText:

```
PadView *pad = [pads objectAtIndex:5];
[pad setText:@"test"];
```

Comment: it **only** affects the object that has been created in the last loop-round? or, it **also** affects the object that has been created in the last loop-round?

Comment: Sorry to tell you that, with this context, it is difficult to solve your problem. It may be possible if we see your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
UILabel *label;
```

are defined in the `@implementation` block, so they are effectively global variables (in the `C` sense).

So basically, all your instances of `PadView` will change the same `UILabel` when you set its text property (which explains the behavior you are seeing).

I'm lacking some context, but it seems that you want `label` to be an instance variable instead (and I'd assume `player` as well). If that's the case, you need to declare them in the `@interface` block as follows:

```
@interface PadView : UIView {

    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    UILabel *label;

}

- (void)setText:(NSString*)text;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`pads` is not initialized

```
NSMutableArray *pads = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
```

and you must release pad after adding as subview and to the array

By convention the class should be named `PadView`, not `padView`

**edit**

```
for(padView *pad in pads){
    //manipulate each pad 
}



//manipulate a certain pad
padView *pad = [pads objectAtIndex:5];
pad. //...
```

Comment: I already initialize the array in that way. Forgot to mention that sorry. Releasing didn't bring a change though. But what do you mean with initializing pad? InitWithFrame etc. should be an initialization shouldn't it?

Comment: or describe more precisely, what u want to do?

Comment: Do I need a UIViewController for my custom UIView? Right now I just bequeath (google translator?!) my custom UIView from the UIView class 
(PadView : UIView )

Comment: what I want to do: 
I'm working on an app with 8 pads, every pad includes an avaudioplayer
when i touch a pad the touched-pad should start to play but the app always just plays the last initialised pad, no matter which pad i press

Comment: You should add that to the original post, so that everyone will be aware of it.